# Graph isomorphism from equivalence relation

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I know that any graph isomorphism defines an equivalence relation on said graph. But now I have some equivalence relation on a graph. Is it possible to construct an isomorphism? Intuitively I would say yes maybe even multiple ones (I am not sure how many...) since I can map elements in each equivalence class to elements in the same equivalence class in such a way that their neighborhood relationships are preserved.

But is their a canonical formal way of writing down the corresponding isomorphism?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can define an equivalence relation on a graph so that equivalent vertices don't even have the same degree, so you're not going to get a graph automorphism out of that.

Comment: Was that helpful?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You explained that it does not work in general graphs so I look deeper into my specific example. And in my case it is possible due to the link between my graph and the AR

Comment: In general, canonical forms for graphs can be constructed in quasipolynomial time (https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10179675). If you are looking at a specific family of graphs, it may be possible to do so in polynomial-time or even in parallel (NC).